# Component link in custom metadata on Keyword

Tags: tridion

We have a metadata schema that has 3 fields in it - 2 text fields (title & summary), one component link field.
Its being used by our keywords and the taxonomy published to the broker.

However when we assign values and publish, in the broker's [CUSTOM_META] table for the keyword, we only see the 2 rows for the two text field entries and nothing for the component link field. I was hoping to see a third row for the component link showing a TCM ID or something to represent the component linked to.

In fact, when you look at the database table design for [CUSTOM_META], it only seems to support KEY_DATE_VALUE, KEY_STRING_VALUE & KEY_FLOAT_VALUE.

**Does this mean that the value in a component link field can't be published to the broker?**

We where going to use this TCM to generate a link to a published page, so I guess we can change the field type to text and just ask editors to type url in or use Bart's [Item Selector](http://www.sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/itemselector.aspx) to pick the page itself.

This is in a Tridion 2011 SP1 env. - everything configured to be published to the broker by default, (apart from binaries and a couple of specific page types).

Comment: Did you check with Tridion CS? I quickly tested, keyword metadata with component link is not going to custom_meta, other information is going in. Sounds like a bug,  or (intended by design, not sure of a reason) .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is fixed in 2011 SP1 with hotfix CD_2011.1.0.79212, downloadable from:
https://www.sdltridionworld.com/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=/downloads/hotfixes/SDL_Tridion_2011_SP1/index.aspx
(login required)